# Page loads standalone but hangs in iframe under other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This page http://pagelinks.mxhoste.com/readings_page.php loads standalone, if you type the address in the browser.  But it hangs when I load it as an iframe with `.load()` under another page:

Here is http://pagelinks.mxhoste.com/readings.php where I have an iframe to load the page.

```
<iframe src="readings_page.php" scrolling="no" style="position: relative; top:-25px; width:97.5%; height:95.2%; border:10px solid #404040; overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
<script>
    document.title = "PageLinks | Daily Readings";
    $("#menu ul li").removeClass("active");
    $("#menu ul li:eq(1)").addClass("active");
    show_alerts();
</script>
```

That code by itself also loads in the browser.  It only hangs when I load the file in another page element on click of a button with

```
$(#page).load('readings.php');
```

Here is the html for that element:

```
<div id="page"> 

</div> 
<style>
#page {
    font-family:"Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:0.8em;
    width: 778px;
    height: 435px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    background-color: #404040;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
}
</style>
```

Is there a different way to load readings.php to get around this problem?  In other words what is the best way to load the page readings_page.php into a div on my main page.  The method that I have with the iframe hangs.

Comment: By hanging do you mean you can tell the page is still loading? Or does it just not show up? Also, does it happen in other browsers? I had a problem loading another page in via jquery in IE and it was because of some invalid html in the page I was trying to load in.

Comment: Are you attempting to .load() cross domains?

Comment: The error is the "long running" script error on both IE and Safari.  All the files are on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Load your readings_page.php inside your readings.php when DOM gets ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // DOM is ready now
  $(#page).load('readings.php');
});
```

Comment: I load the readings.php onclick after the page load is complete.  There must be a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the frame needs only show after the user performs an action, consider loading the content when the page loads (and hide the frame or a div containing the frame when the page loads).

If you need it visible as soon as the page loads, then I would recommend trying to combine the source of your two pages on the server side before sending it rather than having the user's browser make separate HTTP requests.